# How does one clean up a stale CIFS mount

Tags: kernel, cifs

I have a recurring problem where I need to mount a drive of a Win32 machine on my LAN so I can read and write files to it.

But I have no control of said machine, and as such, said machine frequently gets turned off or rebooted without warning.

And as such, I get directories that I'm "in" and files that are open turning into kernel level blocks, and I can't even `kill -9` these processes, and have to wait well over 15 minutes for those mount points to start expiring.

And thats even *with* using `umount -a -t cifs -f -l`.

Nothing I can do seems to alleviate this problem, and I frequently get non-advice such as

- Don't mount non-servers and expect them to work
- Get the person I'm trying to access the files of to not use
  Samba/CIFS
- Get them not to turn their computer off.

The last one is especially incredulous considering Win32's propensity to need regular reboots.

A way to tell the kernel "Look, that mount is not going to come back, please stop blocking everything waiting for it to come back" would be nice.